# Ubuntu 18.10 chrome youtube problem

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome, video, youtube

I have installed Ubuntu 18.10 a few days ago and encountered strange error while playing youtube videos in Chrome. When I try to open a video,  the screen just says: "An error occurred. Please try again later. (Playback ID: some number)". However, if I refresh the current page, the video plays normally, but strangely enough, all the comments, descriptions and suggested videos disappear, and are replaced just with a white background. This also prevents me from listening youtube playlists. Then, if I type another video name in the search bar and hit enter, the music from the previous video still plays, even if I open a new video. However if I refresh the tab, I can listen to the new video (but with the white background again).

I tried allowing flash, didn't help. <s>I didn't update Chrome, but I've just installed it so I don't see a point in doing that</s> As recommended, I made sure that both Chrome and my system are up to date. I couldn't find the answer anywhere so far, so maybe one of you knows what's going on.

Comment: Youtube currently (and since a very long time) does not depend on Flash. Chrome, like any browser, should be updated. If you installed it with the .deb file provided by Google you now have the Chrome repository added to your software sources. That means Chrome updates will be delivered along all the other system updates. Please update your system before anything else. Try again, [edit] and also update your question with what's happening after the update.

Comment: Updated my question. The problem is still the same.

Comment: Same problem, except it doesn't resolve when I refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, turns out I had a youtube Chrome app installed that I was using a couple years ago. After uninstalling it everything is ok.